# How to use the "old" Intent Chooser Dialog?

Tags: dialog, android-5.0-lollipop

Android 4.4 has this chooser dialog and the new Chrome version uses this dialog-"look" as well.

[image: old style]

But the new Intent.createChooser() looks like this:

[image: new style]

How can I get the old "look"?

Comment: Chrome isn't using the framework chooser. You would need to create your own, and I would strongly recommend against that. Why do you want the old chooser?

Comment: Because I like the old look more,but if that's not possible to choose between them, it's okay.

Comment: why would you want to do that? i'd rather look for a library to make the intentchooser look everywhere like this...